# Range subtraction in the Excel Object Model

Tags: .net, excel, range, libraries

When using Excel Interop libraries from .NET, I can find a Range object representing the cell offset from Range X by calling something like.

```
Range Y = X.Range[2,3];
```

But what should I do to perform the inverse operation, ie:  I have two Range objects, `A` and `B`, and I would like to find out by how many rows/columns `B` is offset from `A`.

Does anyone know the easiest way to do this?  Is there a library function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want Longs returned?

```
RowOffset = B.Cells(1,1).Row - A.Cells(1,1).Row
ColOffset = B.Cells(1,1).Column - B.Cells(1,1).Column
```

That will tell you how much the top left cells are offset.